# Problema al crear cookie en PHP y JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, php7, php5

En mi archivo index.php tengo esto:

```
<script>
function logear()
{   
    var correo = $("#correoVal").val();
    var password = $("#passwordVal").val();
    
    $("#btn_login").attr('disabled','disabled');
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/acciones/usuario/login.php",
        data: "correo=" + correo + "&password=" + password,
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function(){
            $(".img-carga").removeClass("ocultar");
        },
        success: function(data){
            if(data < 3)
            {
                if(data == 1)
                    window.location.href = "docente.php";
                else
                    window.location.href = "alumno.php";
            }
            else if(data == 3)
            {
                Swal.fire('Correo incorrecto', '', 'error');
                $("#btn_login").attr('enabled','enabled');
                $(".img-carga").addClass("ocultar");
            }
            else
            {
                Swal.fire('Contraseña incorrecta', '', 'error');
                $("#btn_login").attr('enabled','enabled');
                $(".img-carga").addClass("ocultar");
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

y en mi archivo login.php tengo esto:

```
<?php
include_once("../../clases/class.Usuario.php");

extract($_POST);
# correo
# password

sleep(10);

$usuario = Usuario::getUsuario(trim($correo));

if(is_array($usuario))
{
    $password = htmlspecialchars(trim($password));
    
    if(password_verify($password, $usuario["password"]))
    {
        setcookie("id_usuario", $usuario["id_usuario"], time() + 31536000); 
                    
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["id_usuario"] = $usuario["id_usuario"];
                  
        session_write_close();
        
        echo $usuario["status"];
    }
    else
        echo 4;
}
else
    echo 3;
?>
```

El problema es que no quiere crearme la cookie, la variable de sesión si la crea pero la cookie no, cual es el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Retorna un obj json

```
echo {"status":$usuario["status"],"cname":"id_usuario","cvalue":$usuario["id_usuario"]};
```

En el ajax

```
success: function(data){
 if(data.status < 3){
  ......
  setCookie(data.cname, data.cvalue, 1)
  ......
 }
......
}
```

Agrega la funcion js para crear la Cookie

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
   const d = new Date();
   d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
   let expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
   document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
 }
```